# Strange CSS margin problem

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm styling a form designed by a client with the following structure:

```
<div class="formRow">
    <div class="fieldName">
        Email
    </div>
    <div class="fieldInput">
        <input .../>
    </div>
</div>
```

The width of the form is 500px, but the fieldName div and the fieldInput div stack on top of each other instead of sitting side-by-side.  This is because (at least in Chrome and Firefox), the fieldName div is getting a computed right-margin of 340px, taking up the entire width of the form.

I can't seem to override this behavior, either.  Entering a margin-right of 10px does nothing.  And setting the width of the div either to a hard number or a percentage only changes the inside width, not the strange right-margin.

What CSS headache am I running up against, here?

BTW, here's the CSS:

```
.formRow{
    padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.fieldName{
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 100px;

}

.fieldInput{
        width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: you'll definitely need to post the css.

Comment: CSS/HTML questions are better asked on http://doctype.com, not on SO.

Comment: Have you inspected it in Firebug? Looks like you might have looked at the 'layout' pane, but one that tells you what CSS rules are applicable should give you the answer.

Comment: @EBGreen - *that* is somewhat controversial

Comment: @annakata - Not according to the SO FAQ. I'm not sure how much more plainly it could be expressed: "web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype. "

Comment: Whose title is 'designer'? From the way the question was phrased, it's likely that they're doing a form layout in preparation for writing code to handle the input.

Comment: yeah... it would seem absurd to think that all CSS/HTML work is considered designer work.  Infact, I don't know a lot of designers who CAN do this type of work!

Comment: So we think it is a good idea to bifurcate where CSS/HTML questions should be asked? I'll go to meta to see if this has already been discussed.

Comment: Ok, after looking at MSO, I will be forced to ask everyone's job title when there is a CSS/HTML layout question apparently.

Comment: Personally I'd rather SO remained an unfractured central source, but it'll be the community's decision under Jeff's direction ultimately. Nonetheless, 5 upvotes on my earlier comment says it's not just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to take note of in your example code is that you are over-using DIVs. The same code could be written like this:

```
<div class="formRow">
    <label class="fieldName">Email</label>
    <input class="fieldInput" .../>
</div>
```

Or, even better:

```
<style type="text/css">
    UL, UL LI
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
     }

    UL LI
    {
        list-style: none;
    }

.fieldName{
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 100px;

}

.fieldInput{
        width: 200px;
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li><label class="fieldName">Email</label>
        <input class="fieldInput" .../></li>
     ...
</ul>
```

By using DIV tags for both sections you are violating the semantic meaning of the tag, which is "this section of the page is distinct from this other section." What you really are trying to do is just style your Form `label` differently from your `Input` and we already have tags to describe those.

Comment: You're right.  Using the display: inline gave me a jaggy form, which is what I was trying to avoid.  This works much better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
.fieldName {display: inline}
```

or

```
.fieldInput {display: inline}
```

or both

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `display: inline;` to each element, that will allow them to sit side-by-side. Because they're rendered as `block` elements by default, the browser puts them on their own lines.

```
.fieldName{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline;    
}

.fieldInput{
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
}
```